# integrate wordnet with solr

Tags: lucene, solr, wordnet

I am trying to integrate wordnet api in to Apache solr. But it is not seems to be working and there is no good documentation as well. Could you please post me the steps if any body has experience on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more than one way to do this:

1) https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2347
2) https://gist.github.com/562776

These are simple Java classes, which extract the synonyms from WordNet's prolog file - more or less the same way. Hope this helps.

Péter