# integrate wordnet with solr7.5.0

Tags: java, python, solr, lucene, wordnet

I am beginner in solr7.5.0 and I don't know each and every modules of it. As I'm building question answer system I want to integrate wordnet so I can get better query responses. I googled it and found some methods and previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188218/integrate-wordnet-with-solr?rq=1) but I'm really confused on how to do in solr version 7.5.0 step by step.

**Edit**: solr7.5.0 having [WordnetSynonymParser](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_5_0/analyzers-common/index.html?org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/WordnetSynonymParser.html) class, So if anyone worked on same please guide me how I can use this class or is there another way to do it? and can I use python to do it?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [article](https://docs.websolr.com/article/177-using-wordnet-with-websolr) is very useful for this question, and the integration of wordnet can be done by, there are WordNet prolog file('wn_s.pl') which has synsets, we can convert it to synonyms.txt which can be consumable by Solr. So, to convert wn_s.pl file we can use [Syns2Syms.java](https://gist.github.com/bradfordcp/562776). It generates Synonyms.txt which we can index to solr.

But WordNet expansion will only yield marginal gains in relevance if it is domain specific search, so simply creating your own synonyms list based on the common tokens in your index will give more relevance.