# Synonym Graph Filter with synonyms file in Wordnet format not working

Tags: solr, lucene, synonym, solr-schema

I am using Solr 8.3 and trying to pass a synonym file in **wordnet** format, such as-

s(300880586,1,'augmented',s,1,0).

s(300880765,1,'enhanced',s,1,0).

s(300881030,1,'hyperbolic',s,1,2).

s(300881030,2,'inflated',s,1,1).

In the managed-schema file, I have configured the **Synonym Graph Filter** as-

```
  <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="wn_s.pl" format="wordnet" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="wn_s.pl" format="wordnet" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" />
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

However, it did not work. Perhaps I might have missed some configuration or maybe some issue with format.

So I tried converting the file into Solr format, it works that way somehow.

I wanted to use the wordnet format only, so if anyone can help me understand the mistake I am making here, it would be helpful.

Comment: You have different filenames (`synonyms.txt` and `wn_s.pl`) in your indexing and query definitions. Are they supposed to be different (using `synonyms.txt` as the file name seems like you might have forgotten to change it)?

Comment: Sorry about the goof-up, the original file is ```wn_s.pl``` for which I am having the issue , I have updated my post.

Comment: [Solved] There is no issue with ```wn_s.pl``` and ```wordnet``` format. I was searching for ```tiny``` against  ```small``` in the indexed data, however in ```wn_s.pl``` file, ```small``` was NOT a synonym for ```tiny```. I was using this post's help to convert ```wn_s.pl``` file(synonyms) into ```solr``` format - [integrate wordnet with solr7.5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54977463/integrate-wordnet-with-solr7-5-0/55135529#55135529) and the generated ```synonyms.txt``` file( solr format ) was somehow having ```small``` as a synonym for ```tiny``` , hence the confusion!